# Angular Material: not showing second validation message

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-material

I'm having a problem with an md-input-container when I have two validations applied to my input tag. I'm using ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }", but the problem occurs even without it. For example:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Description:</label>
    <input name="description" ng-model="list.description" type="text" ng-minlength="3" required />
    <div ng-messages="listForm.description.$error">
        <div ng-message="minlength">List description is too short</div>
        <div ng-message="required">List description is required</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

If I type "Te" and then press TAB, the ng-minlength validation message shows. But if then I leave the input empty, the required message does not shows (but the input is decorated, as it should be).

The same behavior is reproductible here (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input). In the Erros -> Description input, if I type more than 30 characters then empty the input, the message is not shown. But if I type a correct value and then empty the input, the message shows.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `minlength` and `required` is kind of same thing. So you must either one of them. See the for the example link.
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/PNjdBz

Even if you don't specify `ng-minlength` in `input` it will show error in `ng-message` because it is the same thing. So I think you should use `ng-message-exp` to check both the condition. And the link you refered to material design docs in releated to `maxlength` and `required` while you are looking for `minlength` and `required`.

Comment: Whats wired in the example you posted is that if I add a
    <div ng-message="maxlength">List description is too long</div>

on the first input, it will show too (if the input is blank)

Comment: I was using same `name` attribute on all of those `input` so it was behaving unexpectedly .

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with Angular Material and ngMessages.

Subscribe to the following issue if you want to be notified about any progress. I do the same...

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6767

If you must solve this immediately then you can make use of the workaround described over there but bear in mind that it's not aesthetically perfect.